# MYSQL command line, import command override current database?

Tags: mysql

If I use command

```
mysql -u root -pdb_pass testdb < database.sql
```

I was wondering if a database which already exist and has data, does it override current database? Or must to `DROP DATABASE` (and create it) before to import SQL? For example: I have `database_one` (origin) and `database_two` (copy of `database_one`), I want to update my `database_two`, but on `database_one` I created and edited some tables and indices/foreign keys and columns. If on `database_two` the table already exist does it create the new column which I created on `database_one` (or FK...)?

Comment: That depends on what `database.sql` contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is based on the sql in database.sql.
if it has `drop database` sql in it,it will doing drop database.
I suppose the database.sql is created by mysqldump,typically it will not include `drop database` sql.
but in case it has `drop database`,you could open the sql with editor check on it.
for tables,has the same logic with database,but typically it would drop table.
actually `database.sql` from mysqldump is purely sql we known,there is no mystery in it.

Comment: Yes, I used `mysqldump testdb > /home/ubuntu/database.sql`

Comment: so you can view the `database.sql`

Comment: Yeah, It doesn't drop database, but drop table. Works for me

Comment: great.by the way.the `mysqldump` command has options like `--add-drop-database` `--add-drop-table` to help you customize the created sql file.

Comment: I guess it include line to create exactly same database (name and charset) `mysqldump testdb > /home/user/database.sql --add-drop-database`